# How do i start and stop application state in ASP.NET

Tags: httpwebrequest, refresh, httpcontext

What seems to be happening is on a request some values I have retrieved are being stored in application state, but when I make changes to the values, the old values are still in application state for a while before finally going.

I want a way to refresh the application state on each request.?

Comment: Application state is supposed to be persistent, I'm not sure that this question makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Use Application.Lock and Application.Unlock to ensure multiple users cannot overwrite others changes, and also to ensure users are using the correct Application values.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf9xhdz4(VS.71).aspx